# CSS - How to center Absolute Position div with max width in IE9,10,11

Tags: css

I need to center absolute position div that has `max-width`.

Here is an example. https://jsfiddle.net/allegrissimo123/3VHuK/1/

```
.mess{
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #212121;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-bottom: 50px;    
    max-width: 350px;       
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

I test this in in IE9,10,11 but it does not work.

Comment: Cool that you name your class `.mess`, even if it probably stands for message :-)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assign `width` for the class.

```
.mess{
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 auto;
background: #212121;
color: #FFFFFF;
margin-bottom: 50px;    
max-width: 350px;       
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
z-index: 1000;
width:100%; /* add this */
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/3VHuK/4/)

Comment: And ensure no parent div has width: 0

Comment: adding `width: 100%` fixes this nicely.

Answer (score 1):

This will put your div in the center(Vertically and Horizontally). You don't have to provide margin in this case. The below code can be applied to any div regardless of it's width. Make sure the parent div should have **position:relative or absolute or fixed;**.

```
    .mess{
     /*your other properties here*/
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, tested in IE8:

```
.mess{
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background: #212121;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   margin-bottom: 50px; 
   max-width: 350px;        
   position: absolute; 
   top: 50%; 
   left: 50%; 
   -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
   -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
   transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
   z-index: 1000;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this updated css. This will center align an absolute div vertically and horizontally.

CSS

```
.mess{
    max-width: 350px;
    max-height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom:0px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/3VHuK/2/)

Comment: Fails on every single modern IE